# What to do with MASM assembly org segment

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I search in internet but its really hard to find

a proper discription of **MASM ORG Directive**

i found a **NASM ORG Directive description** in **StackOverlow**

but someone says that **it can be differ from assembler to assembler**

So, i want to know the **specific meaning** and **what to do with this segment**

and I am new to **assembly**

thanks in  advance

**HAPPY CODING**

Comment: MASM doesn't have an `.ORG` directive, neither does NASM for that matter. Both have an `ORG` directive, but they're slightly different.

Comment: thanks, there is a mistake in the tutorial that i am following

Comment: i am using emu8086 emulator for learning assembly

Comment: and i am following a MASM assembly tutorial

Comment: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.1.1: Unlike MASM, NASM's `org` directive doesn't let you jump around in the output file; it just tells the assembler what address to assume when referencing labels in this section.  Oh nvm, you're only asking about MASM, not both.

Comment: emu8086 isn't MASM. Don't use a MASM tutorial when using emu8086.

Comment: ok, then what should i follow